# Sublime Text 3 shows no menu bar on Arch Linux unless launched as root

Tags: arch-linux, sublime-text, aur

I don't get a menu bar visible in Sublime Text 3, downloaded from the AUR using `packer -S sublime-text-dev`.

This seems to be a fairly common issue, however none of the solutions around the Internet have solved the problem for me. This includes:

- Going through the config files and changing any instance of "menu_visible" to equal "true"
- Adding some code to the launcher file
- Pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and then typing in "Show Menu" to show the menu

None of these had any effect. I should also note that additionally themes aren't visible unless I launch as root.

I have tried reinstalling the software, removing the config folder, and even trying Sublime Text 2; none of these things worked.

At this point, I'm at a loss, so I hope some of you have suggestions. Thanks in advance.